# Show more precise data points on scatterplot

Tags: r

I'm trying to study the distribution of weight (1 d.p numeric) vs age (integers). I tried using the following plot script:

```
babyData <- read.csv("baby2.csv", colClasses = c("NULL", NA, NA))      
plot(babyData$Weight, babyData$Age, 
  main = "Distribution of Weight across ages",
  sub = "Scatterplot of Baby Weight vs Age",
  pch = 10,
  cex = 0.5,
  xlab = "Age",
  ylab = "Weight")
```

And this is the resulting scatterplot:
[image: Resulting Scatterplot]

This is how my data looks like:
[image: Dataset]

As you can see, my Weight column has 1 decimal place but the plot function automatically rounds it and snaps to integers. How do I make the data points more precise down to 1 d.p? I tired googling and looking at documentations but I can't seem to fix it.

Thank you for your help and attention, sorry if this problem has been solved before.

Comment: You should post reproducible data rather than an image of your data. See [dput](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/dput) for one way to do this.

Comment: Your Y axis spans from 0 to 40 and you want to put 400 tick marks on it? That's going to look like one big black stripe.

Comment: Also, its very weird that your **data points** seem to be snapped to integers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535706/r-plot-decimal-point-accuracy-on-the-axis Change your x axis to be more accurate

Comment: @Spacedman Yea that's the problem I have with, I guess it's wrong to say ticks. My Weight data is 1.dp numeric but it's snapped to integers. Any ideas why?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `plot(babyData$Age, babyData$Weight, ...`? You had the y argument before the x argument without labelling them.